# Downloading Files with different filetypes from REST api

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Hello I'm trying to implement some filemanager in a light version.
On the server side Im using Java Spring Boot / Rest API the method looks like this:

```
InputStream inStream = fmService.downloadFile("...url..." + path);
    
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inStream, response.getOutputStream());
response.getOutputStream().flush();
```

And the frontend uses Angular. Where Im trying to get from the url like this:

```
downloadFile() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'responseType': 'blob'}); //also tryed array buffer or text

    this.http.get("http://localhost:8080/file?path=/Documents/Nextcloudflyer.pdf&filename=Nextcloudflyer.pdf", 
    {headers: headers}).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log("RES: ", res);
    });
}
```

When I use downloadFile() Im getting the following error now:

[image]

First problem is: Although Im trying this with an pdf, **I need it working for all filetypes**. But how exactly? (heard of something like octet-stream type? But was not able to get it to work.) Is there an easy way or do I really have to handle every filetype on its own, like I saw it sometimes?

The second problem is the error of course: What is happening here? I'm putting a bytestream into the response and seems like Angular gets it (get is code 200 so seems ok). But what went wrong? Did I construct the ByteArray in a false way? Or is some header set wrong or forgotten?

Comment: What happens when you access the file link directly?

Comment: Managed to get it working for PDF: response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);
  org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(inStream, response.getOutputStream());
  response.getOutputStream().flush();
  inStream.close();   

But first Problem: I can't get the content-type easily (only idea: switch on filename ending, but, hm...) 
Second problem: The filename is now some cryptic id, although the file gets downloaded and can be opened.